# Serialized Properties do not change in custom editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, editor

I created an object and editing it with a custom editor
private variables are edited via SerializedProperties

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Serialization;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Video;

[CustomEditor(typeof(StreamVideo))]
public class StreamVideoEditor : Editor
{
    StreamVideo script;
    private SerializedProperty _playOnAwake;
    private SerializedProperty _hideObjectOnStart;
    private SerializedProperty _loop;
    private SerializedProperty _Object2hide;
    private SerializedProperty _volume;


    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        script = (StreamVideo)target;

        _playOnAwake = serializedObject.FindProperty("playOnAwake");
        _hideObjectOnStart = serializedObject.FindProperty("HideObjectOnStart");
        _loop = serializedObject.FindProperty("loop");

        _Object2hide = serializedObject.FindProperty("ObjectToHide");
        _volume = serializedObject.FindProperty("Volume");

        RequiresConstantRepaint();

    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        _playOnAwake.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Play on Awake", _playOnAwake.boolValue);
        _hideObjectOnStart.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Hide Object On Start", _hideObjectOnStart.boolValue);
        _loop.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Loop", _loop.boolValue);

        if (_hideObjectOnStart.boolValue)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(_Object2hide, new GUIContent("Object to hide"));
        }
        ...   
      }
    }
```

no error and everything is shown fine **BUT**
I cannot change any object which is defined by a serializedObject.
I can't for instance to change any toggle;

there is almost no info about it on the web
has anyone encountered the issue?
got any solution?

Comment: In your `OnInspectorGUI()` method, try to add `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` at the very end.

Comment: As Malphegal already said: you are not writing back the serialized values so in the next frame/call your serialized values get overwritten again by `serializedObject.Update`. General note: Rather simply use e.g. `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_playOnAwake);` for all your properties (no return value). It automatically uses the correct drawer according to the property type, including the display name.

Comment: thanks, that indeed solved the issue
derHugo, i tried and it seems like only properties I serialized in the editor scripts can be viewed using `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField` is that correct?